CMake issue linking to external project
I'm trying to add BoringSSL as a dependency of my library, using C++ with CMake for Android.
Here is what I'm doing:
add_library(mylib STATIC
    foo.cpp bar.cpp .....)

ExternalProject_Add(
        boringssl
        GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/google/boringssl.git"
        GIT_TAG "origin/master"
        SOURCE_DIR "external/boringssl"
        STEP_TARGETS crypto ssl
        CMAKE_ARGS "-DOPENSSL_SMALL=TRUE"
)

add_dependencies(mylib boringssl)

target_link_directories(mylib PRIVATE
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/boringssl/install/lib")
target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE
    crypto ssl)


The linker for "mylib" fails with "ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lcrypto" and "-lssl" and here is the weird thing:
Even though I use target_link_directories, the linker command line as printed out does not include the .../boringssl/install/lib directory. This directory doesn't exist at configure time (since ExternalProject_Add runs at build time) but that shouldn't be a problem, right?
I must be doing something wrong, what is it?
Broader question - I want to include BoringSSL as a dependency of my library, what's the best way to do it if not ExternalProject_Add ?

Edit: here is the linker command line, as you can see it's missing the link directory (my library is called srtc):
--target=aarch64-none-linux-android29 --sysroot=/mnt/android/sdk/ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--no-undefined-version -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libsrtctest.so -o /home/kman/Android/proj-srtc/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/5963472j/obj/arm64-v8a/libsrtctest.so CMakeFiles/srtctest.dir/jni_class_map.cpp.o CMakeFiles/srtctest.dir/jni_error.cpp.o CMakeFiles/srtctest.dir/jni_util.cpp.o CMakeFiles/srtctest.dir/jni_peer_connection.cpp.o CMakeFiles/srtctest.dir/srtctest_main.cpp.o  srtc/libsrtc.a  -landroid  -llog  -lcrypto  -lssl  -latomic -lm && :
  ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lcrypto
  ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lssl


Have you tried to follow that answer and specify an absolute path to the crypto and ssl libraries in the target_link_librzaries command?

Yes I have, and doing a clean build fails because ninja can't find the absolute library file which doesn't exist yet (since ExternalProject runs at build time)

PS - target_include_directories is working just fine

Oh, so you are using ninja. Have you checked that question and its answer?
